# dictionary and array counting with underscore

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

This is a very trivial question, but I'm simply seeking a elegant approach considering underscore is quite powerful.

I have an array of dictionaries like this:

```
dict = [{name: 'bob',
         tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']},
         {name: 'alice',
         tags: ['tag1']},
         {name: 'John',
         tags: ['tag2', 'tag3']}];
```

I would like to return an array like this

```
result = [
  {tag1: 2},
  {tag2: 2},
  {tag3: 3}
];
```

In other words, I want to count the number of occurrences of all appearing tags. This is obviously achievable with just a few for loops but I'm wondering if there's an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first flatten the `tags` array and get the count of each tag. Then generate the object with tag and its count.

```js
var dict = [{name: 'bob', tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {name: 'alice', tags: ['tag1']}, {name: 'John', tags: ['tag2', 'tag3']}];
var result = _(dict).chain().map('tags').flatten().countBy().value();
var output = _(result).keys().sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})).map(k => ({[k]: result[k]}));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Native JS Solution.

```js
var dict = [{name: 'bob', tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {name: 'alice', tags: ['tag1']}, {name: 'John', tags: ['tag2', 'tag3']}];
var result = [].concat(...dict.map(({tags}) => tags))
          .reduce((r,tag) => {
            r[tag] = (r[tag] || 0) + 1;
            return r;
           }, {});
var output = Object.keys(result).sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})).map(k => ({[k]: result[k]}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: say that I have my `result` array but it somehow wasn't sorted by their values, so something like: `result = [
  {tag1: 3},
  {tag2: 1},
  {tag3: 2}
];`, how am I to sort them?

Comment: Updated the solution.